# datatables on select event fired multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In my Java project, with JSP, I've added a DataTable inside a popup window like the following:

```
<table id="table" class="display"  style="width:100%">
        <thead>
           <tr>
               <th class="select-checkbox sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 7.41667px;" aria-label=""></th>
               <th class="thHidden">Id</th>
               <th class="thHidden">Id order</th>
               <th>Data</th>
               <th>Number</th>
               <th class="thHidden">Id customer</th>
               <th>Company</th>
            </tr>
       </thead>
    </table>
```

and the following js script:

```
if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#table')) {
                    table = $('#table').DataTable({

                        ajax: {
                            "url": url,
                            method: "post",
                            data: function(d){d.param= $("#param").val()},
                            headers: headers,
                            dataSrc: ""
                        },
                        columns: [
                            {"data": "", "defaultContent": ""},
                            {"data": "id", "defaultContent": ""},
                            {"data": "idOrder", "defaultContent": ""},
                            {"data": "data", "defaultContent": ""},
                            {"data": "number", "defaultContent": ""},
                            {"data": "idCustomer", "defaultContent": ""},
                            {"data": "company", "defaultContent": ""}                                
                        ],

                        columnDefs: [
                            {
                                data: null,
                                defaultContent: '',
                                orderable: false,
                                className: 'select-checkbox',
                                targets: 0
                            },
                            {
                                targets: 'thHidden',
                                visible: false
                            },
                            {
                                targets: 3,
                                render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment('MMM D, YYYY H:mm:ss A', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                            }],

                        language: {
                            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.11.3/i18n/it_it.json"
                        },
                        select: {
                            selector: 'td:first-child',
                            info: false
                        },
                        order: [[3, 'asc']]
                    });
                }
                else {
                    table.rows().deselect();
                    table.ajax.reload();
                }

                table.on('select', function (e, dt, type, indexes) {
                    if (type === 'row') {                         
                        alert("row selected");                              
                    }
                });
    
                table.on('deselect', function (e, dt, type, indexes) {
                    if (type === 'row') {
                        alert("row deselected");
                    }
                });
```

In this way I can select and deselect rows. For the first popup opened, everything works fine, but when I close a popup and reopen a brand new (with new data in the table reloaded), the events of selection and deselection are called multiple times for each row selected/deselected.

I would like to understand why the .on() is fired multiple times.

Comment: You can try removing select/deselect event listeners by using `off` before table is reloaded.

Comment: it seems your solution works correctly. Please @CodeThing add it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment,

You can remove select/deselect event listeners by using `off` method before table is reloaded.

Reference: https://datatables.net/reference/api/off()